# Remove specific lines after matching a pattern

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have a file like below:

```
chs_de_le_q1gg
fd_tr_mn_0
fd_tr_mn_06
fd_tr_mn_070
fd_tr_mn_0716
fd_tr_mn_09013
fd_tr_mn_092433
fd_tr_mn_1020333
fd_tr_mn_12013332
dsdas_1
dsdas_12
dsdas_212
sdasd_4567
weqwe_32323
dasds_232322
2321321_rewrwe_3233
32_Ff
asdasd_1_fff
```

I need to remove the lines ending with digits ranging from 4-8 of length; also to remove lines starting from numbers.

the below works to match the lines which I want to delete, but then doing invert match on that match with adding `-iv` doesn't work.

```
cat test.txt | grep -oP '(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4,8}(?![0-9])'
```

Comment: Since you only want to delete lines of up to 8 digits at the end, you should include lines with more than 8 digits at the end in your example so we could test that a potential solution actually works. Also, add the expected output for your posted sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### To remove lines which:

- starts with a digit: `^[0-9]` or `^\d`
- or ends with 4~8 character length of digits: `[0-9]{4,8}$` or `\d{4,8}$`.

  ```
  grep -vE '^[0-9]|[0-9]{4,8}$'  infile >output
  sed -E '/^[0-9]|[0-9]{4,8}$/d' infile >output
  grep -vP '^\d|\d{4,8}$' infile        >output
  ```

##### To remove lines which:

- starts with a digit: `^[0-9]`
- or ends with ***exactly*** 4~8 character length of digits: `[^0-9][0-9]{4,8}$` or `\D\d{4,8}$`.

  ```
  grep -vE '^[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]{4,8}$'  infile >output
  sed -E '/^[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]{4,8}$/d' infile >output
  grep -vP '^\d|\D\d{4,8}$' infile            >output
  ```

Comment: thank you so much.. one more doubt, in case if we want to ignore 1-2  & 4-8  digits ending at last. then ?

Comment: @rose that's `([0-9]{4,8}|[0-9]{1,2})$`

Comment: @rose FYI that's a question, not a doubt. A doubt means you don't believe something, a question just means you want to know about something. If you don't think a solution will work then you have a doubt about it, if you want to know how to extend a solution then you have a question about it. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2429 for one discussion on the topic.

Comment: how to include multiple grep in this, incase if i want to exclude _ff in the same query ?

Comment: @rose `grep -vE 'exclude1|exclude2|exclude3|...|excludeN'`, _exclude#_ is an expression that you wish to exclude lines with that conditions. so for `_ff` you will need `grep -v '_ff'` to exclude lines that ***contains*** the string `_ff` everywhere in the line; you can add end of line `$` or start of line `^` anchors per your need. if you have a new question please ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '!( /^[0-9]/ || /(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{4,8}$/ )' file
chs_de_le_q1gg
fd_tr_mn_0
fd_tr_mn_06
fd_tr_mn_070
dsdas_1
dsdas_12
dsdas_212
asdasd_1_fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Below deletes lines starting with a digit, or containing runs of 4-to-8 digits adjacent to the line ending (`unless` is synonymous with `if not`):

```perl
raku -ne '.put unless /^ \d | \d ** 4..8 $ /;'
```

Sample Input:

```
chs_de_le_q1gg
fd_tr_mn_0
fd_tr_mn_06
fd_tr_mn_070
fd_tr_mn_0716
fd_tr_mn_09013
fd_tr_mn_092433
fd_tr_mn_1020333
fd_tr_mn_12013332
dsdas_1
dsdas_12
dsdas_212
sdasd_4567
weqwe_32323
dasds_232322
2321321_rewrwe_3233
32_Ff
asdasd_1_fff
```

Sample Output:

```
chs_de_le_q1gg
fd_tr_mn_0
fd_tr_mn_06
fd_tr_mn_070
dsdas_1
dsdas_12
dsdas_212
asdasd_1_fff
```

Note: Above would delete a line such as `fd_tr_mn_123456789`, since 8-digits are adjacent to the `$` end-of-line. If the OP desires to retain runs of digits *greater-than* 8-digits adjacent to the line ending, the following regex works:

```perl
raku -ne '.put unless /^ \d | \D\d ** 4..8 $ /;'
```

Above, a line such as `fd_tr_mn_123456789` would be retained in the return.

https://raku.org